# How to correctly autoadjust key width for proportional fonts?

Tags: fonts, gnuplot

I came across this issue when checking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77796264/7295599).
As you can see, the autosizing for the graph width (or key width) works fine for monospaced fonts, however, not for proportional fonts. I expected that gnuplot would determine the width of the textbox and then would adjust the graph width accordingly.

I don't want to have identical graph widths, but I want to have the same spacing between graph and the `15xiiiiiiiiiiiiiii` and the `15xmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm` title (worst case example) for proportional fonts.

Is there maybe a workaround for this?

**Script:**

```
### how to correct space for proportional fonts
reset session

myTitle(i) = word("short 15xiiiiiiiiiiiiiii 15xmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm",i)
set samples 20
set ytics 0.5

set multiplot layout 6,1
    do for [i=1:6] {
        if ((i-1)/3) {set key out font "Arial"}
        else         {set key out font "Courier New"}
        plot '+' u 1:(rand(0)) smooth cspline w lp lc "red" ti myTitle((i-1)%3+1) 
    }
unset multiplot
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]